# How to get @font-face css from FontFace object?

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, type-conversion, font-face

You can get a list of all loaded fonts through `Array.from(document.fonts.keys())`

This returns an array of [FontFace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFace) objects.

How do you convert a FontFace object to `@font-face` css rule.

The main problem I'm facing is that there is no `src` property on FontFace Objects. And `src` property is required to make a `@font-face` rule.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  src: url(sansation_light.woff);
}
```

Comment: I have looked into this a few months ago, but I gave up as it is a bees nest, maybe you will have more luck with it:
As an example this page [Type Scale](https://type-scale.com/) loads a list of Google Fonts into a dropdown the user can select on-the-fly. Also [Adobe Typekit: WebFontLoader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader) may point you in the right direction.
BTW, `document.fonts` returns a reference to the documents `FontFaceSet` interface. Essentially the *engine* that controls the loading process of fonts, not an array of `FontFace` objects as you mentioned.

Comment: Just found another one on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/borian/pen/kGZZWK)... Maybe there is hope after all!

Comment: Seems like not a lot of hope actually with `FontFace` method. Will have to approach this from a different angle. P.S Thanks for correcting me.