# How to get all fonts from a page including the src/URL of each font?

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, font-face, google-font-api

So I need to get the list of fonts used by a webpage I can't control, including the src/URL of the font.

The best way I know to get the fonts is to use `documents.fonts`, but I don't know how to get the src/URL from the `FontFace` object returned by `documents.fonts`.

Need to support both fonts loaded from Google Font and also fonts loaded by user CSS.

I can't use this because the google stylesheet is giving error `Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules` because of CORS issue.

```js
const styleSheets = Array.from(document.styleSheets);

styleSheets.forEach(styleSheet => {
  const cssRules = styleSheet.cssRules;
});
```

I'm wondering if it's even possible to do this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

For external `@font-face` rules added via `<link>` or `@import` you first need to fetch these stylesheets.

```js
btnOutput.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  outputFontReferences()
})


async function outputFontReferences() {
  let fontRefs = await getFontReferences();
  textareaCSS.value = JSON.stringify(fontRefs, null, 2);
}

/**
 * check all styleSheets
 * external link or imported stylesheets
 * need to be fetched and inlined
 * to create font Files object
 */
async function getFontReferences() {
  let fontFiles = [];

  // inline external css
  let styleSheets = await inlineExternalCss(true, true);

  styleSheets.forEach((styleSheet, s) => {
    let cssRules = styleSheet.cssRules;

    for (let i = 0; i < cssRules.length; i++) {
      let rule = cssRules[i];
      let typeRule = rule.type;

      // type===5: is @font-face rule
      if (typeRule === 5) {
        let style = rule.style;
        let fontFamily = style.getPropertyValue('font-family').replaceAll('"', "");
        let fontWeight = parseFloat(style.getPropertyValue('font-weight'));
        let fontStyle = style.getPropertyValue('font-style');
        let unicodeRange = style.getPropertyValue('unicode-range');

        let src = style.getPropertyValue('src')
          .split(",")
          .map((val) => {
            return val.split(" ")[0];
          })
          .filter(Boolean);
        let url = "";

        // extract font file URLs/paths
        src.forEach((fontSrc) => {
          url = fontSrc.match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1].replaceAll('"', "");
        });

        // add to fontFiles object
        fontFiles.push({
          origin: origins[s],
          fontFamily: fontFamily,
          fontWeight: fontWeight,
          fontStyle: fontStyle,
          src: url,
          unicodeRange: unicodeRange
        });
      }
    }
  });

  console.log(fontFiles);
  return fontFiles;
}

/**
 * inline all external stylesheets
 */

// collect all css origins
let origins = [];

async function inlineExternalCss(removeExternalCss = true) {
  let styleSheets = Array.from(document.styleSheets);

  /**
   * stylesheet helper
   * fetch external css
   */
  const fetchExternalStylesheet = async(href, ind = 0) => {
    let fetched = await fetch(href);
    let css = await fetched.text();
    let newStyle = document.createElement("style");
    newStyle.classList.add("externalCSS");
    let externalCss = document.head.querySelectorAll(".externalCSS");
    if (!externalCss.length) {
      document.head.insertBefore(newStyle, document.head.children[0]);
    } else {
      document.head.insertBefore(
        newStyle,
        externalCss[externalCss.length - 1].nextElementSibling
      );
    }
    newStyle.textContent = `/** origin: ${href} **/\n` + css;
    origins.push(href);
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < styleSheets.length; i++) {
    let stylesheet = styleSheets[i];
    let href = stylesheet.href;

    // fetch external stylesheet
    if (href) {
      await fetchExternalStylesheet(href, i);
    } else {
      let cssRules = stylesheet.cssRules;
      let cssRulesL = cssRules.length;
      for (let r = 0; r < cssRulesL; r++) {
        let rule = cssRules[r];
        let type = rule.type;

        // is @import rule - fetch external stylesheet
        if (type === 3) {
          let href = rule.href;
          if (href) {
            if (removeExternalCss) {
              stylesheet.deleteRule(r);
              cssRulesL--;
              r--;
            }
            await fetchExternalStylesheet(href, r);
          }
        } else if (type === 5) {
          origins.push("local");
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // remove external stylesheet
  if (removeExternalCss) {
    let styleSheetLinks = document.querySelectorAll(
      'link[href$=".css"], link[rel="stylesheet"]'
    );
    for (let i = 0; i < styleSheetLinks.length; i++) {
      let link = styleSheetLinks[i];
      await link.remove();
    }
  }

  let styleSheetsInlined = Array.from(document.styleSheets);
  return styleSheetsInlined;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,500;1,300&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: "Fira Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 20em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<h2>Log loaded fonts referenced in CSS</h2>
<p><button id="btnOutput">list all fonts</button></p>

<textarea id="textareaCSS"></textarea>
<script>
  async function outputFontReferences() {
    let fontRefs = await getFontReferences();
    textareaCSS.value = JSON.stringify(fontRefs, null, 2)
  }
</script>
```

#### How it works:

1. We loop through all stylesheets – retrieved by `Array.from(document.styleSheets)`
2. If any of the stylesheets contain a `href` property:  we can fetch this source and inline the css conent as a new `<style>` element
3. if a rule is of **type "3"** it's an `@import` rule – we also need to inline this source
4. Once all stylesheets are inlined, we can loop through the new array of stylesheets
5. `@font-face` rules can also be detected by their **type: "5"**
6. We can get the font's url by selecting the `rule.style.src` property

#### Limitations:

This approach can't retrieve file URLs from fonts loaded via [`new Fontface()` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFace/FontFace) since, the fontFace object doesn't contain any `src` properties (as described here ["How to get @font-face css from FontFace object?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72332584/how-to-get-font-face-css-from-fontface-object) )

Comment: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: style.fontFamily is undefined`; although this may only be a problem with Firefox, as it works correctly on Chrome.

Comment: @David Thomas: thanks for testing. I can't reproduce this error. Do you get it running the snippet?

Comment: The error was reported in my browser's console, not the snippet (or snippet console); I haven't explored it as I'm a little short of time, but I'm running Firefox 111.0.1, on Ubuntu 22.10 if that helps at all.

Comment: @David Thomas: Thanks for your feedback! I will also check this. You might also fork this [codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/JjazXLo)

Comment: @David Thomas: I could finally fix this issue: In firefox we need to use `style.getPropertyValue('font-family')` instead