# How do you find out which CSS code is loading a font file in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

I have a WordPress site, if I look into the sources tab in Chrome I see certain fonts being loaded from the theme.

[image]

After a lot of trial and error, I could see two of the fonts being loaded using @font-face in the style.css of the theme. However, I am still unable to find where the third font visual-composer-starter-font.woff2. is being loaded from.

Since this type of work would be fairly common to my new job, I wanted to ask how do I find out using Chrome which CSS code is loading this font. Since the @font-face will be located inside a CSS file and since there are a large number of CSS files being loaded from different folders I don't think searching for the font file (like I am doing in the screenshot below ) for each CSS file would be viable.

Any tips?

Comment: What you see to the left is just a file in a folder. It's not necessary to be loaded. It will be loaded if it's mentioned somewhere in the CSS and if this HTML item is on the page. Try to find the font name in the CSS files. If it's not there, then the font is not loaded at all.

Comment: First check the **network tab** and filter fonts. This view will only show actually loaded fonts. E.g if a font-family wasn't applied in any css rule it won't be loaded (thus, not show up). For a more complete list of all fonts referenced in you css you might try the JS approach explained here ["How to get all fonts from a page including the src/URL of each font?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73866391/how-to-get-all-fonts-from-a-page-including-the-src-url-of-each-font/75857870)